# Exclude cpp from folder without deleting

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, build, java-native-interface

I'm currently working on a Java project using JNI for an Android app. My project requires the use of external libraries which are stored on my computer, outside of the project folder, in the form of .h/.cpp files.

I have included the folders that contains the required files by creating "linked folders". My problem is that these folders also contain files that need not to be included. And these files are being compiled too, despite the fact that i didn't mention them in my Android.mk

I tried excluding them manually using properties -> C/C++ Build -> Exclude from build, but it doesn't work, i'm getting a NullPointer error from eclipse.

What can I do please ? Thank you.

Comment: Well i think i found a way : right click on cpp's, build configuration and exclude from build. The cpp's are now greyed, but they are still being compilted. Doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile the majority of the files in a directory and just exclude a few of them you could use `wildcard` and then exclude files with `filter-out`:

```
# set SRC_FILES_LIST to all the .cpp files in $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo/bar/
SRC_FILES_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo/bar/*.cpp)

# exclude $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo/bar/baz.cpp
SRC_FILES_LIST := $(filter-out $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo/bar/baz.cpp, $(SRC_FILES_LIST))

# set LOCAL_SRC_FILES to the files in SRC_FILES_LIST, without the initial $(LOCAL_PATH)/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SRC_FILES_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```